# Microk8s gpu alloc by vram size

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, kubectl, microk8s

I have microk8s node with different type gpu. ( RTX A5000, Rtx A2000)
I install nvidia-gpu-operator and it reports this node has two "nvidia.com/gpu"
[my label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4UVG.png)[allocatable gpu is 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrDZd.png)
Two gpu has different vram, few job works well in A2000, but some heavy job always fail when it allocated in A2000.

I have already know label in k8s, but it works for only different node.

My question is, is there any solution for select each gpu when i create pod in single node?
or is it possible disable one gpu on node?
if it's impossible to select gpu when i start pod, i just want to don't provisioning A2000 in node.
also, it's impossible to remove hardware. and i don't want to disable a2000 in host system.

is there any solution?

I try to set visible devices for volume mounts
[volume-mounts](https://github.com/NVIDIA/gpu-operator/issues/372)

and set env on nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset env

[nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLtEr.png)